# How can I send a parameter to a component with UI-Router?

Tags: angularjs

Angular version: **v1.5.11**

UI-Router version: **v0.4.2**

I am trying to send a parameter based on the URL to a component. However, it looks like the parameter I am trying to read inside of the component is out of scope. I've tried researching this for a while and reading the docs but am unable to figure this out.

When the URL is: **/#!/phones/motorola-xoom**

The output in the browser is:

> TBD: Detail view for {{$ctrl.phoneId}}

I think the relevant code is as follows:

**./app.config.js**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('phonecatApp')
    .config(['$locationProvider', '$stateProvider', function($locationProvider, $stateProvider){
        $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');

        var phoneListState = {
            name: 'phone-list',
            url: '/phones',
            template: '<phone-list></phone-list>'
        };

        var detailState = {
            name: 'phone-detail',
            url: '/phones/{phoneId}',
            component: 'phone-detail',
            resolve: {
                pid: ['$stateParams', function($stateParams){
                    console.log($stateParams.phoneId);
                    return $stateParams.phoneId;
                }]
            },
            template: '<phone-detail></phone-detail>'
        };

        $stateProvider.state(phoneListState);
        $stateProvider.state(detailState);
    }]);
```

**./phone-detail/phone-detail.component.js**

```
'use strict';

angular.
  module('phoneDetail').
  component('phoneDetail', {
    bindings: {pid: '<'},
    template: 'TBD: Detail view for <span>{{$ctrl.phoneId}}</span>',
    controller: [function PhoneDetailController(pid){
      this.phoneId = pid.phoneId;
    }]
  });
```

You might notice the line: *console.log($stateParams.phoneId)*

That seems to print "motorola-xoom" to the console. For some reason, I am not able to read it inside of my component.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

**Edit 1:**

The error I see in console is:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'phoneId' of undefined
>       at new PhoneDetailController

This occurs on line 10 of **./phone-detail/phone-detail.component.js**

```
this.phoneId = pid.phoneId;
```

Which kind of makes sense to me based on the first comment from JB Nizet. Based on [this documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing) under the **$stateParams Service** section, I was under the impression that the "key"(?) that was first defined in the resolve could be arbitrary -- apparently I am misunderstanding something important here, as that does not appear to be the case.

I have tried using **$stateParams.phoneId** in the controller, but it still fails to interpolate.

Alternatively, I've tried dropping the component from my state definition entirely and tried something like

```
var detailState = {
    name: 'phone-detail',
    url: '/phones/{phoneId}',
    template: 'TBD: Detail view for <span>{{$ctrl.phoneId}}</span>',
    controller: ['$stateParams', function PhoneDetailController($stateParams){
        console.log($stateParams.phoneId);
        this.phoneId = $stateParams.phoneId;
    }]
};
```

The value I expect prints in the console, there are no errors in the console, but interpolation still fails.

---

**Edit 2:**

[image]

---

**Solution:**

The solution from "Edit #2" was almost correct. An alias needs to be added.

```
var detailState = {
    name: 'phone-detail',
    url: '/phones/{phoneId}',
    template: 'TBD: Detail view for <span>{{$ctrl.phoneId}}</span>',
    controller: ['$stateParams', function PhoneDetailController($stateParams){
        console.log($stateParams.phoneId);
        this.phoneId = $stateParams.phoneId;
    }],
    controllerAs: '$ctrl'
};
```

Additionally, [here](https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/route-to-component) is a good resource about routing to components as referenced by @nicooga.

Comment: If the ourput is `Detail view for {{$ctrl.phoneId}}`, then you most probably have an error in the console preventing angular to interpolate this expression. Read it and post it. Why don't you use $stateParams.phoneId, since you know that this contains the value you expect. What is `pid`supposed to be, why would it be injected in your controller, and why would it contain your state parameter?

Comment: @jb-nizet Thanks for your suggestions. I have updated my original post with "Edit #1" to answer your questions and post the requested error(s).

Comment: Your fix is the right one. The resolve is completely useless, since all it does is returning something that is trivially available in the $stateParams. In your original code, `bindings: {pid: '<'}` doesn't make sense, since pid is a resolve, and not a component attribute. And `[function PhoneDetailController(pid)` should have been `['pid', function PhoneDetailController(pid)`. I strongly advise you to stop using this awfu array notation, and to use ng-annotate to do it for you. I don't see how the interpolation could fail with the code you have now, and without any error in the console.

Comment: @jb-nizet As can be seen from "Edit #2," the code with my fix is being loaded, there are no errors in the console, my $stateParams.phoneId property can be printed to the console, and there are still interpolation issues.

Thanks for the information about my original code. I am following the AngularJS (phonecat) and UI-Router tutorials to the best of my ability, but am coming up short here. What would be the proposed solution if I wanted to send parameters to a component, as I originally attempted to do? I'm not looking for any direct answers necessarily -- links to good references work.

Comment: Have a look at https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/route-to-component

Comment: @nicooga just what I was looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The solution from "Edit #1" is almost correct. An alias needs to be added:

```
var detailState = {
    name: 'phone-detail',
    url: '/phones/{phoneId}',
    template: 'TBD: Detail view for <span>{{$ctrl.phoneId}}</span>',
    controller: ['$stateParams', function PhoneDetailController($stateParams){
        console.log($stateParams.phoneId);
        this.phoneId = $stateParams.phoneId;
    }],
    controllerAs: '$ctrl'
};
```